# Rownum or Fetch/offset is good to select and process million of records

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I would like to read million of records from oracle and transfer to another table through Java.  Due to some reason we are using Java process we are going this.

I would like to ask best approach to select records from tables for examples 1000 records at a time..  Whether rownum is good or Fetch/Offset in 12c?

for example if the table has 10000 records following query i may use.

```
select *
from table
first 500 rows only  -- first time

select *
from table
offset 500 next 500 rows only
```

... second time  ( Is this time oracle again fetch 1000 records and send 500 rows to Resultset ..)

```
select *
from table
offset 1000 next 500 rows only
```

....Is this time oracle again fetch 1500 records and send 500 rows to resulset...

... so on

so I am not sure the best approach whether Rownum to select 500 records at a time or offset/fetch approach... need advise..

Comment: [We need tool support for keyset pagination](https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset)

Comment: the two tables are in the same database  or are in different database?

Comment: Why would you use Java to move tables around? I'd suggest Data Pump instead.

Comment: *"Due to some reason we are using Java process "* is the reason you want to do this in an extremely inefficient fashion?

Comment: we cannot use any tools right now and due to security reasons we are doing our custom framework to transfer data..also so many design issue in the tables and recreating the table doing some massage then do transfer..so using java

Comment: this is from one db to another db

Comment: If you have to use this architecture, you should try to open one cursor and stream the results from it, rather than opening 2000 separate cursors.

Answer (score 0):

You want to pull millions of rows out out of a table in database #1, pull them down a relatively low-bandwidth connection to a Java app so you can massage them, then you want to turn around and push those same rows UP that same connection, to stick them into a database #2 - can you see why this may not be a good choice? :-)

Better - build a temp table in database #1, then once your temp table is populated push the data from database #1 to database #2 using an Oracle-to-Oracle database connection.

Something like:

```
Database #1
  CREATE TABLE TEMP_TABLE AS
    SELECT FIELD1,
           FIELD2,
           SUM(FIELD3)  -- or whatever
      FROM TABLE1
      WHERE WHATEVER = SOMETHING_ELSE
      GROUP BY FIELD1,
               FIELD2

  Run whatever PL/SQL procedures, etc, are needed to massage your data and make it 
  pretty.

Database #2
  CREATE TABLE PRETTY_BRAND_NEW_TABLE AS
    SELECT *
      FROM TEMP_TABLE@db1;
```

In my experience that's your best option. YMMV.

Best of luck.

Comment: it's from oracle to mysql db.

Comment: my question is how oracle internally doing offset/fetch.

Comment: for example table has 10000 records. offset 9000 fetch 500 means oracle select all records then skip 9000 or select only 9001 to 9500..